# how to get multiple occurrences in a string with substring?

Tags: c#

I want to get all the game names from a string to a list, How can I do that without getting the same name again?

I have tried to use for loop like in the example below my error was that I got the same name again then I try to remove the keyword name so it will just skip to the next one but the keyword is shown multiple times and I cannot remove it

I have tried:

```
List <string> list = new List <string>();
int GamesAmount = 2;
string games = "Name: game1, StatusName Name: game2,";
for(int i = 0;i < GamesAmount; i++) 
{
    string currentGame = games.Substring("Name: ", ",");
    list.Add(currentGame);
    games = games.Remove(0, IndexOf("name") + 4);
}
```

at the end I want

`list[game1, game2];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got a clean list the upper answers will work just fine. In addition I'd suggest to use a `Regex` to make it possible to use more complex patterns.

#### Example

```
// some crappy input string with upper and lower case and spaces only sometimes before the game name.
string inputString = "Name: game1, StatusName Name: game2, Bla bla Name: game1, Some more Text StatusName Name:game3"; ;

// Define a pattern (explaination on the bottom of this answer)
Regex gameName = new Regex("Name:[ ]?(?<GameName>[^,]*),", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Create a "list" which will contain the names in the end
HashSet<string> GameNames = new HashSet<string>();

// Loop through all substrings which match our pattern
foreach (Match m in gameName.Matches(inputString))
{
    string name = m.Groups["GameName"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Found: " + name); // what did we match?

    // add game to list if not contained
    GameNames.Add(name);
}

// Let's see what we got
Console.WriteLine("All Games: " + string.Join(", ", GameNames));
```

#### Output

> Found: game1
>
> Found: game2
>
> Found: game1
>
> All Games: game1, game2

#### Regex-Explaination:

```
Name:[ ]?(?<GameName>[^,]*),

Name:  // Has to start with this string
[ ]?   // A space-Character, which can occur 0 or 1 time ("?"). ([x]? would be a x 0 or 1 time)
(....) // is a group which can be accessed later
(?<name>) // is a group named "name" which can be accessed by name later
([^]+)    // is a group containing any character except comma. 1 to infinite times ("+")
,         // Match has to end with a comma.
```

#### Linq-Style

And if you like Linq and understood what you're doing, you can run queries on your matches:

```
    var instantList = new Regex("Name:[ ]?(?<GameName>[^,]*),", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) // Create Regex
        .Matches(inputString) // Get Matches to our input
        .Cast<Match>() // Cast to Ienumerable<Match>
        .Select(s => s.Groups["GameName"].Value) // Select Gamename from Match
        .Distinct(); // remove doublicated
```

Comment: Checking `!GameNames.Contains(name)` is redundant - just `GameNames.Add(name)` will do the job and reject duplicated names.

Comment: @fabio totally correct. Was a List<T> before i changed it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all names start with `colon` plus `space` and end in `,`:

```
            string games = "Name: game1, StatusName Name: game2,";
            var splittedText = games.Split(':');
            var currentGame = splittedText.Select(x => x.Length > 4 ? x.Substring(1, x.IndexOf(",") - 1) : "")
                .Where(y => y != "")
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for answering! but it contains a random amount of character that I cannot predict

Answer (score 2):

Split by comma, then split by `Name:` and use `HashSet<string>` to return only unique game names

```
var gameNames =
    games.Split(',')
         .Select(game => game.Split('Name: ').LastOrDefault())
         .ToHashSet();

foreach (var gameName in gameNames)
{
    // use game name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split sentence into words and check condition where word contains `game` in it

Something like

```
    string games = "Name: game1, StatusName Name: game2,".Trim(','); //Remove last , from string
    List<string> g = games.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Contains("game")).ToList(); //Use of Linq
    foreach(var i in g)  //Iterate through list to print
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

If `game` string is not constant in string then you can use below approach, it need just one extra for loop

```
    string games = "Name: game1, StatusName Name: game2,".Trim(',');
    List<string> str = games.Split(',').ToList();
    List<string>result = new List<string>();

    foreach(string i in str)
        result.Add(i.Split(' ').LastOrDefault());

    foreach(string r in result)
        Console.WriteLine(r);
```

POC : [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8syZ1S)

Comment: yes but the it doesn't actually contain the word game, it contains a random game name

Comment: that means game is not constant, it can be `xyz`. Updating my answer give me some time

Comment: @MosesZaodi Did you check my answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Before adding to List, i think you should simply check either that value already exists in List or not.

```
if(!list.Contains(currentGame))
    list.Add(currentGame);
```

if it is not in List then it should add to your List object.